# react router 4 query parameters example not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

**problem**: trying to implement react router query parameters example on my local environment. code below from their website.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function ParamsExample({ location }) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <p>
          React Router does not have any opinions about how your parse URL query
          strings. Some applications use simple key=value query strings, but
          others embed arrays and objects in the query string. So it's up to you
          to parse the search string yourself.
      </p>
        <p>
          In modern browsers that support{" "}
          <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL">
            the URL API
        </a>
          , you can instantiate a <code>URLSearchParams</code> object from{" "}
          <code>location.search</code> and use that.
      </p>
        <p>
          In{" "}
          <a href="https://caniuse.com/#feat=url">
            browsers that do not support the URL API (read: IE)
        </a>{" "}
          you can use a 3rd party library such as{" "}
          <a href="https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string">query-string</a>.
      </p>
        <div>
          <h2>Accounts</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=netflix" }}>
                Netflix
            </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=zillow-group" }}>
                Zillow Group
            </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=yahoo" }}>
                Yahoo
            </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=modus-create" }}>
                Modus Create
            </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Child name={params.get("name")} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Child({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name ? (
        <h3>
          The <code>name</code> in the query string is "{name}"
        </h3>
      ) : (
          <h3>There is no name in the query string</h3>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParamsExample;
```

when rendering i get the following error message 
 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined` 
 which is pretty straight forward, but when i do `location.search` in my `console` i get the following output `"?name=zillow-group"`
 with that being said `location.search` is a valid property but not sure why react is not seeing it.

Comment: Can you try a console.log(location) inside function paramsExample. And refresh the component. So we can check whether from the initial time of refresh we are getting or not the search property. Please let me know the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're logging location in the console, you are logging the window.location object. In your component, however, there is a location prop defined that takes precedence. It's not shown explicitly in the [react-router example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters), but they are rendering the ParamsExample component somewhere and passing in the location prop.

You can access the react-router location prop (among others) by either using the [withRouter hoc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) or by using the [Route component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route). Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3qm08rqz):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ParamsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <p>
          React Router does not have any opinions about how your parse URL query
          strings. Some applications use simple key=value query strings, but
          others embed arrays and objects in the query string. So it's up to you
          to parse the search string yourself.
        </p>
        <p>
          In modern browsers that support{" "}
          <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL">
            the URL API
          </a>
          , you can instantiate a <code>URLSearchParams</code> object from{" "}
          <code>location.search</code> and use that.
        </p>
        <p>
          In{" "}
          <a href="https://caniuse.com/#feat=url">
            browsers that do not support the URL API (read: IE)
          </a>{" "}
          you can use a 3rd party library such as{" "}
          <a href="https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string">
            query-string
          </a>
          .
        </p>
        <div>
          <h2>Accounts</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=netflix" }}>
                Netflix
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=zillow-group" }}>
                Zillow Group
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=yahoo" }}>
                Yahoo
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/account", search: "?name=modus-create" }}>
                Modus Create
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Route
            render={({ location }) => {
              let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
              return <Child name={params.get("name")} />;
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Child({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name ? (
        <h3>
          The <code>name</code> in the query string is "{name}"
        </h3>
      ) : (
        <h3>There is no name in the query string</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <ParamsExample />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```